# Food is cold, put it on fire or put it on flame?

Tags: sentence-construction

Here I am talking about the gas stove. Can I say "put it on fire" where the fire is actually the flame of the gas stove?

Do I have to say "Put it on flame"? Which one is better? Why?

Comment: Shortest is: *Please* serve hot!

Comment: I would say "put it on the stove".

Comment: "Put it on the fire " with the definite article is the same.Consider thefreedictionary.com.

Comment: The food is cold. You *reheat* it. Specifically, using a **stove**.

Comment: "**the** fire" conjures up images of bits of wood burning, hence I would avoid it in this case.

Comment: @AndyT If I'm sitting by a fire, saying "Put it on the fire" means I want you to warm the thing up in the fire, while saying "Put it on fire" means I want you to ignite the thing. Even if a literal fire isn't immediately available, the article is generally necessary to make this distinction.

Comment: @talrnu - Agreed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess we do not say: **Put it on the fire.**

---

To put something **on** fire/flame might mean to "burn it with fire/flame."

---

The best way is to say, as [Rathony](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73927/food-is-cold-put-it-on-fire-or-put-it-on-flame#comment141814_73927) suggested:

> Put it on the stove/gas

or

> Cook/bake/heat it

This is what we say normally. If you are on a camping trip(and don't have grill or stove) or on some wild expedition, only then say:

> Cook it over the fire.

However, Both fire and flame are similar, yet different. Clear your confusion [here](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-fire-and-vs-flame/)

---

To be more specific and correct, you can choose to say:

> Put it on the [burner](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/burner)

Thanks [J.R](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73927/food-is-cold-put-it-on-fire-or-put-it-on-flame/73935?noredirect=1#comment141831_73935)

Comment: I'd be inclined to say, "Put it on the [burner](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/burner)."

Answer (score 12):

I usually use ***burner*** in this context:

> *Don't use the microwave; put it on the burner*.

As [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/burner?a=british) says:

> **burner** (*n*.)  the ​part of a ​cooker, ​light, etc. that ​produces ​flame or ​heat

A *burner* can apply to a gas or an electric stove. Although I wouldn't usually say, "Put the food on the flame," the word *flame* is often used in cooking contexts; for example:

> *Heat the onions [over a low flame](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22over%20a%20low%20flame%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).*

Comment: +1. In the UK you might be more likely to put it on the **hob** than the burner; but if you used burner you would be widely understood.

Comment: I'm British and I've never heard a hob referred to as a burner, but I could guess what was meant. I'd use hob, but could be more specific and say ring (electric) or gas.

Comment: @thelem - Great info! It might be worth adding an extra answer for the UK version. I'd find it interesting and probably upvote it.

Answer (score 5):

### Put it on the fire

Native speakers normally only say *Put X on the fire* if they mean that X should be burned up -- a standard example is

> Put another log on the fire

meaning that a wood fire is burning low and needs additional fuel.  But you might also say

> Put those documents on the fire

meaning that the documents should be destroyed by the fire.  In both cases, you may hear *in* instead of *on*.  *In* is natural when the additional item would appear to be inside the existing fire, and *on* is natural when it would appear to be on top of the existing fire.

However, in the unusual-nowadays situation that you are actually cooking over an open fire (perhaps you are camping in the wilderness?) it would be reasonable to say *put the food (back) on the fire* and people would understand that the food should be heated and not destroyed.  (If you really meant to destroy the food -- e.g. to dispose of bones so they don't attract scavenging animals -- you could say to put it *in* the fire.)

### Put it on the flame

*Flame* is a count noun; it is only used in the singular when there appears to be *one flame* and not an entire fire's worth of *flames*.

The fire produced by a gas stove's burner is considered to be a single flame, and you may hear people say *turn the flame up/down* to indicate that the intensity of the fire (and therefore the amount of heat produced) needs to be increased or decreased.

However, you cannot put anything *on* a flame, because a flame is an insubstantial cloud of gas/plasma and *it can't hold anything up*.  One might put something *in* a flame to heat it, but that means to put the object literally inside the flame, so you'd almost never say that about food.  It is more likely to come up in metalworking, for instance.

### Put it (back) on the *stove*

This is normally how one would ask for food to be heated or reheated in a modern kitchen (if you don't want to use the conventional or microwave oven to do it).  A pot being heated by a cooking stove is *on* the stove, because the structure that physically supports it is a component of the stove.  It is also said to be on the *burner*, whether or not the stove actually burns anything; if you are cooking with any kind of stove, *burner* refers to one of the positions on the top of the stove, each of which can independently heat something.  It is *not*, however, on the *fire* (even for a gas stove) because the component that the flames emerge from is not physically supporting the pot.

The word that refers specifically to the thing supporting the pot is *trivet* for a gas stove, *burner* or *heating element* for a traditional electric stove, and *stovetop* for a glass-top electric stove.  If you are designing or repairing a gas stove, *burner* refers specifically to the component that the flames emerge from, but this is not the usage while cooking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the clearest phrasing would be this:

> *Put it on the stovetop*

Or more colloquially:

> *Put it on the gas*
>
> *Put it on to heat*

Or older usage:

> *Put it on the hob*